# MongoDB design - Same document with multiple keys

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

I'm completely new to MongoDB, and I'm confused on how to structure the data. What I need to do is storing a set of objects which can be retrieved by different keys. For example, I have the object "CustomerInfo" and it can be referenced by keys "Customer1", "Customer_1", "Cust.1", "Customer 1" and so on.

In an RDMBS I would create a separate table to store the aliases, and have a single row for the Customer Info data. Then I'd join them, using whatever alias I get from the Customer, and get to the data. It seems simple and straightforward, but, so far, I couldn't get past creating an empty database. It seems that my experience with RDBMS is more of a hindrance than an asset in this case, as I tend to "think relational" and it (obviously) doesn't apply to NoSQL databases.

Any suggestion is welcome, thanks in advance for all the answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you cannot translate from an alias to an actual ID inside your app (which is always preferred) one option is to simply store an "aliases" array in your MongoDB documents and index on that :

Store documents like so :

```
db.customers {
    aliases : ["Customer1", "Customer_1", "Cust.1", "Customer 1"],
    ...other customer info data...
}
```

Add your index :

```
db.customers.ensureIndex({aliases:1})
```

And then simply query on any of them, all of these will return the document above :

```
db.customers.find({aliases: "Customer1"})
db.customers.find({aliases: "Customer_1"})
db.customers.find({aliases: "Cust.1"})
db.customers.find({aliases: "Customer 1"})
```

The index is optional but will dramatically improve performance.

Comment: This answer is correct. In most cases where you have a one-to-many relationship, like in this case one customerInfo having many aliases, it's the best solution to embed the many-objects as an array in the one-object. I could only think of two cases where you should use references instead of embedding: (a) you could get close to the 16MB per document limit or (b) you modify or query the child-objects outside of the context of the parent-object.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it seems a good solution. To answer your question, I *can* translate an Alias to an ID and, in fact, it's what I do with the RBMS. One CustomerData row ID -> many Aliases.

Comment: @Philipp: the customer object *will* be modified outside independently from the aliases, as it always happen in a one to many relationship. Aliases will stay the same (many of them are legacy values, which won't change), customer info will change. Do you suggest I should look into using references, in such case?

Comment: I understand. I was referring to being able to do it in the application rather than based on a database query. If you can't the above is a proper solution for NoSQL.

Comment: @RemonvanVliet Ok, now I understand. Well, original data is (and will) be stored in an RDBMS for the time being, for updates and maintenance. Queries, will instead be served via MongoDB, which will act as some sort of cache during reads. I'm not very experienced with it, but I can see that it provides a great performance boost (and it's perfect to store the results that Users keep asking for, over and over).

Comment: @Diego: You misunderstood me: I would have suggested to use references when the ALIASES would be edited separately from the CUSTOMER objects, not the other way around. By the way: When you are searching for a pure caching solution, Memcached might be even better than MongoDB.

Comment: @Philipp Now it's clearer, thanks. About your suggestion, I'm not sure I would go with Memcached, though, as I'd like to have the data stored permanently, not just in RAM. I'll take it into account anyway.

Comment: I thought you had your relational database for persistence?